# Show "more" button in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've an ActionBar with 2 items, and an extra item which contains several submenus.

I want this last item, to appear like this picture:

[image]

Those three grey/white squared dots on the right, next to that arrow.

I've thought about downloading a PNG whith that image, but I think its not the correct way of doing it.

The first two menu entries, are displayed because I've set in the XML the tag `android:showAsAction="always"`.

I've tried setting different "showAsAction" values but none worked.

Can you guide me?

Thanks.

Comment: "Those three grey/white squared dots on the right, next to that arrow" -- that is not the action bar. That is just part of the Gmail UI. Gmail has a split action bar, consisting of the top gray bar with the email subject line, and the bottom gray bar with the four icons and the overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the third one to `android:showAsAction="never"` and that will put it on the overflow menu

Comment: If I remember correctly, that overflow icon will only be there if your phone does not have a physical menu button. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán: Accessing the overflow is done either by pressing the MENU button (on devices that have it) or via the three-dots affordance in the action bar (on devices that do not have a MENU button). You can read more about this at: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: wanted to force show it... But I guess it's not possible. Thanks